# Why I have set HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO and unset HTTPS on Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https, cloudflare

Recently I updated my website: CMS (Drupal), it's OS (Ubuntu 14.04) and Apache (2.4.7).

The situation is that when surfing on https://example.com/whatever PHP can't detect HTTPS. `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is empty and `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` returns 80. And that causes a problem because Drupal can't detect HTTPS and is serving HTTP files (mixed content).

The only variable that shows that the connection is on HTTPS is  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO, and Drupal doesn't handle this setting for serving content.

<<< I don't have a reverse proxy or any advanced configuration other than LAMP and Drupal, and only one single site. >>> **Wrong, I was running my site with CloudFlare.**

Consider that I don't want a Drupal solution, I've already managed that. I want to know why Apache is not sending PHP the right SERVER vars or what could be wrong with my configuration.

Thanks for your help.

<<< Final Edit >>> **PD: I'm running my site over a reverse proxy, CloudFlare. It's easy to forget that once you install. Check for my answer to see the option that you have to set in order to get the expected SERVER vars.**

Comment: "Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault" Exactly... like Apache, Ubuntu or Cloudflare! Thanks for the "off-topic" moderation. I'm sure this question belongs elsewhere and will help nobody here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot I was using CloudFlare (easy to forget once you installed it). That's why HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO said HTTPS, because I was behind a reverse proxy.

My CloudFlare config under CRYPTO / SSL with SPDY also said: Flexible. **When changed to full then PHP return the expected HTTPS and SERVER_PORT vars.**

Comment: You should accept your own answer, too. Click on the pipe icon on the left.

Comment: ("*Pipe icon*" also known as the tick outline.)